# Poll type form in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, survey

I'm looking for a way to display simple poll type survey on dedicated page, but haven't found an answer to this problem for 2 days now.

Survey needs to have text and dropdown fields, also answers must be visible to logged-in members and must be editable by admins.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Ok I found a Beta plugin called [Extra Comment Fields](http://blog.ideashower.com/post/15147134893/wordpress-plugin-extra-comment-fields) that should work, but I'm having trouble with the database! Extra fields are not stored anywhere! Table this plugin uses (and should create) is called wp_comments_extra, but this table is nowhere to be found. Is there any way to manually crate correct table by backwards- engineering plugin's .php file?

Comment: Many different Survey plugins, but they never really do what I need them to

Comment: If that's the case you need do develop your own custom plugins.